# how to get the installer username in rpm spec file?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to create a rpm package and need to put a specific file in the client home directory. I looked up the macro references for rpm spec and couldn't find the desired macro. the closest thing that I find is %{getenv:HOME} macro which is resolved to the rpm builder's home directory, not the user who is installing the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user installing the package is always **root**. `rpm` packages are always installed system-wide, not for a single user, so it would be messy putting file in the home directory of a user.

You'd better provide some sensible defaults (for example something like /etc/bashrc) and then let the user choose to override them manually with an optional file in their home directory (like ~/.bashrc). The user would have to create this file manually then; it should not be provided by the **rpm**.

Comment: Thank you Chris for answering the question. So you are saying it's a bad idea to put files in the user home directory, right?
Actually I'm installing the package system-wide, but I need to put a file in user home directory to prevent the system to create a new desktop file for my package. when the binary starts for the first time it ask for desktop integration and I don't want that. By the way it is an appimage file.